# History of the Ruins near Chagyl in Turkmenistan

Tags: archaeology, central-asia

In the **Balkan Region** of ***Turkmenistan***, there is a small (possibly abandoned) modern village built on top of what looks to be some sort of ancient ruins near the remote town of *Chagyl*. (Some of the contemporary houses at the site even appear to be using the raised walls of the ruins as fencing.)

[image: Satellite Picture]

You can see a satellite picture of the complex here: https://binged.it/2E9tk3L

(Bing calls this area ***Tuar***, although [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/T%C3%BCwer,+Turkmenistan/@40.842077,55.1642758,2421m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x41d395263c4904fd:0x49debd2bbe999bd1!8m2!3d40.842079!4d55.173031) labels it ***Tüwer***.)

**Is there any information on the history of said ruins or what the area may have been known for before they were, well, ruined?**

It's interesting that the site appears near the path of the fabled **Silk Road**.

It's also interesting that there look like what appear to be man-made path lines [criss-crossing](https://www.google.com/maps/@42.754581,53.2589038,6632m/data=!3m1!1e3) the desert in this general region as well.

*(In more recent satellite pictures, you can see a [modern railroad](https://www.google.com/maps/@42.267006,53.6513376,3365m/data=!3m1!1e3) being built through some of these pathways to the north of the Garabogazköl lagoon at the Kazakhstan border.)*

Comment: Are you sure they're ancient ruins, and not, for example, sheep pens?

Comment: No, I'm not sure what they are, although some of the structures appear to be very long and narrow, something that I would imagine would be unusual for sheep pens. If they are indeed built to contain animals, the walls in some areas seem to be about 5-10 feet thick. (Compare to scale at lower right-hand corner: https://binged.it/2SoSHkW )

Regardless, many of them look to be buried under a healthy coat of sand, which would imply that they are no longer in use.

Comment: It lay in the paths of various Turko-Mongol invasions so it's possible that the ruins belong to one of the indo-european peoples that once lived there. You need to do some study on the region and compare building footprints to neighbouring areas and so forth.